# Can I send a text in the microsoft bot framework emulator before the user sends anything?

Tags: emulation, botframework

I work with the microsoft bot framework in the emulator. I'd like to send a short "Hello, with this bot you can ..." at the beginning. I imagined that the user starts the emulator, connects with the bot and then the bot would send this message.
Afterwards, the user knows what he can do with the bot and can start a conversation.
Is it possible somehow?

Comment: You would receive a message of type `ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate` when the user sends their first message, but the framework can't send a message via the emulator until it's received one.

Comment: @stuartd ok, thank you very much. Is this documented somewhere? so I can show it to my company

Comment: [This page](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/d7d/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_activity_types.html) as the only documentation I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I have used in the past. This is added in the controller in the HandleSystemMessage-method.
I hope this helps you out.

Be cautious with putting important information in this message. Not all channels support the "ConversationUpdate" message.

```
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        string reply = "";

        foreach (var member in message.MembersAdded)
        {
            if(member.Name != "Bot")
            {
                reply += $"Hello {member.Name}!" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reply))
        {
            reply += "Hello, How are you doing? How can I help you today?";
        }
        return message.CreateReply(reply);
    }
```